# Three.js rotation around an object moving position

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

Im trying to get an object I have made a sphere called earth to rotate around another object called sun.
I have the Earth rotating with movement through space but I cant move the sphere around the sun.
I dont know what to do I have tried looking at world space but my program seems to crash and I have tried looking at the parent example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005526/three-js-rotation-of-objects-around-a-sphere) but all this seems to do is rotate it the earth on an axis with no movement around the sun(eg its cords stay at (50,0,0) and rotates on the spot).
This is what I have so far:
(I removed the parent approach)

```
function WebGLStart()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx');

            var RENDER_DIST = 1000,
                FOV = 75;
            var WIDTH = 600,
                HEIGHT= 500;
            var onRenderFcts= [];
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, RENDER_DIST);
            camera.position.z = 100;
            scene.add(camera);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            renderer.setViewport(10, 10, 600, 500);
            canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var sphere;
            var earth;
            init();

            function init() 
            {

                var geometry   = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10.0, 32, 32);
                var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Textures/sun.jpg')
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xf0f0f0, map: texture} );
                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                sphere.position.set(0,0,0);
                scene.add(sphere);

                var geometry   = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10.0, 32, 32);
                var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Textures/earth.jpg');
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture} );
                earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                earth.position.set(50, 0.0, 0.0); 
                scene.add(earth);
            }
            onRenderFcts.push(function(){
                renderer.render( scene, camera );       
            })

            var lastTimeMsec= null;
            requestAnimationFrame(function animate(nowMsec)
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                lastTimeMsec    = lastTimeMsec || nowMsec-1000/60;
                var deltaMsec   = Math.min(200, nowMsec - lastTimeMsec);
                lastTimeMsec    = nowMsec;

                onRenderFcts.forEach(function(onRenderFct){
                    onRenderFct(deltaMsec/1000, nowMsec/1000);
                })
            })
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is a fiddle to help you get started: http://jsfiddle.net/t83pzoj2/.

Comment: ah i see what I was doing wrong I was trying to rotate on the object and not the pivot! Thank you!!